# NestJS Validate Headers using class-transform example

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

I am trying to validate that the headers of the request contain some specific data, and I am using NestJS.  I found this [information](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4798).  While this is what I want to do, and it looks proper, the ClassType reference does not exist, and I am not sure what to use instead.

From the example, the decorator is referring to.

request-header.decorator.ts

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/commom'
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
// The import below fails
import { ClassType } from 'class-transformer/ClassTransformer';
import { validateOrReject } from 'class-validator';

export const RequestHeader = createParamDecorator(
  async (value:  ClassType<unknown>, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {

    // extract headers
    const headers = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers;

    // Convert headers to DTO object
    const dto = plainToClass(value, headers, { excludeExtraneousValues: true });
    
    // Validate 
    await validateOrReject(dto);

    // return header dto object 
    return dto;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than passing the type through a decorator like this, I'd suggest making a custom decorator and setting the `validateCustomDecorators` option for the `ValidationPipe` to `true`. The decorator would look something like

```js
const Header = createParamDecorator((data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  if (data) {
    return req.headers[data];
  }
  return req.headers;
});
```

And now instead of `@Header()` from `@nestjs/common` you can you `@Header()` from this file and get the `ValidationPipe` to run after applying the appropriate type metadata

Comment: I get an error on the `return req.headers[data];` which is stating that the `Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)`

Comment: Probably need to add some type/data checking in the `if (data)`. Something like `if (data && typeof data === 'string') ` and it should be okay.

Comment: Sorry, new to NestJS, and the use of decorators is giving me some grief as they are not a straight flow through in the debugger.  I am using the  ` @RequestHeader HeaderInfo:SVSHeadersDTO` and that is then giving me an additonal error `error TS1237: The return type of a parameter decorator function must be either 'void' or 'any'.
      Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.

    44   @RequestHeader HeaderInfo:SVSHeadersDTO
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
`

Comment: Let me accept your answer as I believe it is correct, as I assumed it would look something like that, since I have worked with the headers and the .getRequest()/.getResponse() in interceptors.  I will have to make a bigger question around it all, as I need to introduce a custom validator as well.

Comment: Try using `@RequestHeader()` as a function, because the decorators are technically decorator factories (meaning they're a function that return the thing)

Comment: The function certainly corrected the error.  I just have to work on the type checking then of data.

Comment: If I understand correctly though, with the OP's approach, we can just add `@RequestHeader headers` to our arguments, but with this approach, now we have to add `@RequestHeader(new ValidationPipe({ validateCustomDecorators: true })) headers`. That seems very verbose. Any way to cut that down?

Comment: @chrismarx by adding the validation pipe globally look at global scoped pipes at the docs

Comment: The validation and transformation doesn't work when requesting single header property (e.g. `Content-Type` - just an example)